# If no mouse over hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link that shows a div on mouse over. 
On mouse out I hide the div again. 
Yet, if the user never mouse overs the div after it opens then it stays open so I need to hide the div after a certain time.
Since these are 2 elements (link and a div) I do not think I can use .hover. How would I best write this to hide .tooltip-profile after 10 seconds of no mouse over?

```
$("#profile").mouseenter(function(){
var position = $(".tooltip-profile").offset();
$(".tooltip-profile").css( { position: "absolute", left: "720px", top: "-110px" } );
$(".tooltip-profile").fadeIn(500);
} );
$(".tooltip-profile").mouseleave(function(){
$(".tooltip-profile").fadeOut(500);
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a callback function to your `fadeIn()` which defines a timeout of 10 seconds. When reached, the time out will `fadeOut()` the element:

```
$("#profile").mouseenter(function () {
    var position = $(".tooltip-profile").offset();
    $(".tooltip-profile").css({
        position: "absolute",
        left: "720px",
        top: "-110px"
    });
    $(".tooltip-profile").fadeIn(500, function () {
        setTimeOut(function () {
            $(".tooltip-profile").fadeOut(500);
        }, 10000);
    });
});
$(".tooltip-profile").mouseleave(function () {
    $(".tooltip-profile").fadeOut(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait for some time using setTimeout on mouseleave during this time if mouse is again on link or tooltip don't hide tooltip.

```
      var keepOpend ;
     $("#profile").mouseenter(function(){ keepOpend  = true;
       var position = $(".tooltip-profile").offset();
       $(".tooltip-profile").css( { position: "absolute", left: "720px", top: "-110px" } );
       $(".tooltip-profile").fadeIn(500);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
          keepOpend  = false;
          setTimeout(function(){
            !keepOpend && $(".tooltip-profile").fadeOut(500);
        }, 500);
    });
    $(".tooltip-profile").mouseleave(function(){
          keepOpend  = false;
          setTimeout(function(){
            !keepOpend && $(".tooltip-profile").fadeOut(500);
        }, 500);
    }).mouseenter(function(){
       keepOpend = true;

   });
```

Comment: I am using this method to function basically as a small drop down bubble for buttons around my site that hide/show divs of dynamic data. Any better ideas of plugins that I could use for this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any specific tooltip plugin but There must be lots of jQuery plugin for tooltips.